# Can NOT insert data into database in migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I am using Rails 3. I don't know if it is the rule of rails that inside migration, it seems I can not insert data into database table. If someone can confirm it is so.

I tried the following things:

I have two ActiveRecord model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  ...
end
```

I have generate a migration file, inside the migration I have:

```
 def self.up
    default_car = Car.new({:name => 'default_car'})
    default_car.save() #I got 'false' here

    User.create!(:car_id => default_car.id}) #I got default_car.id is null value

  end

  def self.down
    default_car = Car.find({:name => 'default_car'})
    default_user = User.find({:car_id=>default_car.id})

    default_car.delete
    default_user.delete
  end
```

I got **false** when I trying to save the default_car to database, and my default_user have **null** car_id.

Is it because in migration, it is **NOT allowed** to store data into database??

Comment: is there any validations in Car model?

Comment: little debug: `default_car = Car.new({:name => 'default_car'}); default_car.save(); puts default_car.errors`

Comment: Right! there are several validations. I am modifying it now. the "errors" gives the place :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create data in migrations, however it is probably best not to, use seeds.rb instead.

Think the above will be failing because your car is not saving, I'm guessing you have some validation in your Car model.

Comment: Right! there are several validations.

Comment: An old rule was, that if you use models in migration, it's best to define the model *in the migration* too. This would help if you later decide to change or even delete the model - the copy in the migration will still work. But if you can - use the seeds.rb.

Comment: Check out the seed_fu gem.  I prefer it much more to regular seeds or fixtures.  Plus it can work into your workflow for your test runs.  I have a script that will recreate the DB and seed_fu before I run all my regression tests, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we've figgured out that there was some validation issues. So you would like to now, that you can skip validations:

```
default_car = Car.new({:name => 'default_car'})
default_car.save(false)
#=> true
```